# Expansion panel isn't expanding

Tags: flutter

`Here in my code ExpansionPanel which is inside ExpansionPanelList. The complication is occurring when I try to expand. It won't expand and when I check Boolean value in ExpansionPanel it is getting false every time.

I have tried List expanded and getting the same result.
In this code I pull the values for a custom string file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tax_calculator/core/values/info-strings.dart';
import '../core/values/app_colors.dart';

class InformationPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const InformationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.colorPrimary,
        title: const Text("Information"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: const SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Center(
              child: BuildExpansionPanel(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BuildExpansionPanel extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildExpansionPanel({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _BuildExpansionPanelState();
}

class _BuildExpansionPanelState extends State<BuildExpansionPanel> {
  final List<Item> _list = generateItems(information.length);
  List<bool> expanded = [false, false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      elevation: 1,
      expandedHeaderPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),

      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _list[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
          print('$index and $isExpanded');
        });
      },
      children: _list.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          canTapOnHeader: true,
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            print('In Panel $isExpanded');
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item.headerValue),
            );
          },
          body: ListTile(
            title: Text(item.expandedValue),
          ),
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  Item({
    required this.expandedValue,
    required this.headerValue,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded = false;
}

List<Item> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
  return List.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return Item(
      headerValue: information[index].title,
      expandedValue: information[index].body,
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've  found your issue...

**Answer in short:**

Change your `expansionCallback` to:

```
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _list[index].isExpanded = isExpanded;
          print('$index and $isExpanded');
        });
      },
```

**Explanation:**

In your `expansionCallback`, you're receiving the target state of your `ExpansionPanel`, not the current state. Meaning, the `isExpanded` shows the state it will have after clicking on the panel. So if your panel is closed, and you click on it, you will get `isExpanded == true`.

In you're code you always revert this new state to the prior state with the negation `!` / `!isExpanded`.

If you remove the exclamation mark (`!`), then your code runs smoothly.

Comment: this will solve my problem fine. You suggestion was correct and explanation was very helpful. Thankyou. But which I forgot to add the main thing to add in the question was I wanted to use ExpansionPanelList like as ExpansionPanelList.radio. So user can expand one panel at a time.